# Service notification when an activity is killed

Tags: android, service, android-activity

My application has an activity and a service running in the same process. When the user terminates the activity by clicking the STOP button, the activity causes the service to terminate.

From the Android documentation I understand that the system can kill a process to reclaim resources:

"Once your activity is stopped, the system might destroy the instance if it needs to recover system memory. In extreme cases, the system might simply kill your app process without calling the activity's final onDestroy() callback, ..."

Question 1: Is it possible for my activity to be killed but not the service? I would prefer my service remain alive.

If the answer is 'yes' then

Question 2: Is there a mechanism where the service can be notified that the activity has been killed?

[IBinder.linkToDeath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/IBinder.html#linkToDeath%28android.os.IBinder.DeathRecipient,%20int%29) has the functionality I need but seems to apply to a process, not an activity.

I've thought of an indirect method like having the activity take ownership of semaphore and having the service use a thread to wait on it. Then when the activity gets killed it will release the semaphore and the service will get it, providing the notification. But I was wondering if there wasn't an android-centric technique I could use.

**[begin edit]**

After reading the very helpful comments you've provided I'd like to clarify the scenario I'm presenting.

I've started two components: an activity and a service. The application is configured so that service can continue to run after the activity has stopped and been destroyed. The user can restart/start the activity multiple times and it will use the same instance of the service.

Normally the activity will notify the service it has been destroyed during onDestroy(). But onDestroy() may not be called.

I'd like to know whether there is some android-specific mechanism I can use to notify the service that the activity has been killed without the call to its onDestroy() method having been made.

**[end edit]**

Thanks for your help.

Will

Comment: If you start service by Context.startService it wont be killed after activity.finish(). You can pass that activity was destroyed by sending a message to the service by handler in onDestroy(), or you can use LocalBroadcastManager

Comment: @Marcin : I was under the impression from reading various posts that, when an activity is killed, its onDestroy isn't called. I'm not worried about the service being killed. Did I read your response correctly? Thanks for answering.

Comment: Normally onDestroy is called. But if system needs more memory it can kill whole application(with all activities and services). It never kills just one activity without calling onDestroy

Comment: If you are confused with different opinions check [this](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/10/03/activities-not-destroyed-to-free-heap-space.html), especially link from that post

Comment: Maybe the case I'm interested in is the 'abnormally' one, where the activity is stopped and then killed. The android docs say, referring to stop(): "... after that method returns the process hosting the activity may killed by the system at any time without another line of its code being executed...". I'm looking for a mechanism to notify the service that the activity has been killed.

Comment: Single activity cannot be killed. Whole process is killed. Documentation is wrong about this. Check the link from my prevoius comment.

Comment: What If I want to clear my SharedPrefrence data when app kills ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said before, single activity won't be killed by android without calling onDestroy(). If Android   needs more memory it kills whole process(with all activities and services). [Here](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/10/03/activities-not-destroyed-to-free-heap-space.html) is description, documentation is wrong about this.

Service can be also created in other process but it has to be set int the manifest. And then you can use [iBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/IBinder.html#linkToDeath%28android.os.IBinder.DeathRecipient,%20int%29) to get notification when process(with all activities) is killed by Android

Comment: When I read your second comment I reread the previous one and saw the link. Sorry about that. I worked up a long answer and tried to post it but learned that I can't post for another 4 hours. I read Mark's post, Dianne's post, and the comments to Dianne's post. Those comments suggested that, if the docs were wrong they should be corrected. This was 2011. Issue 21552 from Nov 2011 formally makes that request. Still, it hasn't been changed. The owls don't appear to agree on this matter. I'll see if I there's a way to kill the activity and see what happens. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Interesting post from commonsware and one that I hadn't read before.

Comment: What If I want to clear my SharedPrefrence data when app kills ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes services and activities can run independently of each other.

To achieve what you're trying to do I would explicitly start your service using startService() in your activity's onStart() function (or wherever you wish to launch it) and also bind to it at the same point. Binding without an explicit startService will cause the service to stop when you kill the activity (unless some other activity is still bound to it).

In your activity's onStop() call a function on your service to tell it the activity has been killed.

In your Activity:

```
private ServiceRecordJourney yourService;
private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {

        YourServiceBinder binder = (YourServiceBinder) service;
        yourService= binder.getService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
    }
};

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));

    // Bind to Service
    Intent intent= new Intent(this, YourService.class);
    bindService(intent, serviceConnection , Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();

    if(yourService != null){
                yourService.activityKilledFunction();
        unbindService(serviceConnection);
    }
}
```

Your service will need to be foreground (and display a notification) to further stop it from being killed off by the OS. Also as it's been explicitly started you will need to handle an explicit stop on the service (either call stopSelf() on the service or stopService() in a context object.

You can handle communication to the service using multiple startService() calls with different intents but I prefer the above approach (and I'm sure that in the case binding is the preferable approach).

Also whilst the service is running the activity will bind and unbind to the service each time the activity is started or stopped by the user.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I understand correctly you're saying that an activity always knows that it is being killed - that the system stops the activity before killing it.  That's a relief as I thought the system would just 'kill' it (like 'kill -9') and it wouldn't have a chance to perform any cleanup. Did I get that right?

Comment: Not quite. Once the activity is "paused"(after onPause() on pre-Honeycomb and after onStop() on Honeycomb plus) then the OS can kill off the activity without calling the rest of the lifecycle (onStop() or onDestory etc etc). Any state saving or communication should be done prior to the "pause" point in the lifecycle. The lifecycle documentation pretty much covers it all: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: I rechecked the document you pointed to but can seem to find an answer to my question. "Any state saving or communication should be done prior to the "pause" point in the lifecycle." I want my service to keep running when the activity is paused. I don't want to save state every time the activity is paused. It may be paused and restarted any number of times. I want to know if it was killed. I presume the activity can be killed but that the application may continue to run with the activity be started again some time later by the user. I'm sorry if I'm not making sense; I'll reread your ref.

Comment: I possible didn't make that point clear. Your service will continue to run and the activity will bind and unbind to it as and when it is required to do so. The save state comment was just to highlight that any thing that must be saved (in the event that the OS kills the application process outright) should be done there. In your case you made not need to do any saving.

Comment: I think you made your point well; I'm just beginning to understand the real issues here and didn't pick up on it right away. I'll need to make sure the activity is prepared to be destroyed in the event that onDestroy() is not called. Thanks.

Comment: What If I want to clear my SharedPrefrence data when app kills ?